# Update ExpandableListView child from handler

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView with children that have text supplied on creation, and an image that is downloaded via a handler on it's group click.

Right now when we click a group, it expands and the text is displayed. The image is downloaded and made into a drawable and inserted into the child's data map. It does not update when it has downloaded, only when another part of the ExpandableListView has been clicked.

EX: I click the first group, text shows up in the new child. I click the second group, the image appears in the child of the first, only text appears in the child of the second.

How can I force the child view to update when it receives the image data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Call that from inside your handler method (ie. once the image data is there).

Comment: I actually found a possible bug with the ExpandableListViewAdapter, it does not have access to the .notifyDataSetChanged(). You can work around this by casting it to a BaseExpandableListAdapter and then calling .notifyDataSetChanged().